# To which railway station did Doug go to leave the city?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-town

In the ending scenes of the movie [***The Town***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0840361/), the FBI officer said to his colleagues to cover the city to trap Doug.

To which railway station does Doug go to leave the city where there would be no FBI people to catch him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no mention of a specific station that Doug went to. Yes, the FBI had covered the city to not let him escape, but he still managed to, being in a disguise.